# /deep/ combinator video range blue css not showing properly

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use the /deep/ combinator to have the range on my video controls to show up blue. Nothing is changing at the moment. Have I made any syntax errors that anyone is noticing? I am using Chrome to work properly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qyjb1Q33DoFGSdUVLv9p?p=preview

```js
var CarList = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
      
      CarList.createdCallback = function() {
        var template = document.querySelector('#car');
        var templateClone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(templateClone);
      }
      
      document.registerElement('car-list', {
        prototype: CarList
      });
      
      var DealerList = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
      
      //Nested Custom Element
      DealerList.createdCallback = function() {
        var template = document.querySelector('#dealer');
        var templateClone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(templateClone);
      }
      
      document.registerElement('dealer-list', {
        prototype: DealerList
      });
```

```css
car-list /deep/ li {
        color: red;
      }
      
      video /deep/ input[type="range"] { background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<video controls></video>
    <car-list>
      <dealer-list></dealer-list>
    </car-list>
    
    <template id="car">
      <ul>
        <li>Ferrari Enzo</li>
        <li>Porsche 91l Turbo</li>
        <li>Dodge Caravan</li>
      </ul>
      <shadow></shadow>
    </template>
    
    <template id="dealer">
      <ul>
        <li>Beverly Hills Ferrari</li>
        <li>Beverly Hills Dodge</li>
      </ul>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `/deep/` [was deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120) on the video element as it [was considered a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=433977#c28). You can, however select the video timeline using `video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline` and set the `background-color` on that.

Comment: I cannot award bounty for 23 hours it says but you will receive it

Comment: It was a very interesting question. Glad to have answered it.